# Upload file & form data with fetch in NuxtJs

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js

How to upload file & form data with feach in NuxtJs

I try `multipart/form-data` & `application/json` but its not work

```
fetch(this.$store.state.apiUrl+'/gf_forms', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

    //make sure to serialize your JSON body
    body: JSON.stringify(this.form)
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(res => {
    console.log(res) 
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I found an article that possibly answers your question.
Take a look at it:
https://muffinman.io/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/

### [Edit]

Since my answer is not considered valuable, I will just add the first sentence from the article at hand in case anyone googles it:

> To upload files using fetch and FormData  you must not set
> Content-Type header.

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. This broken link is an example of why.